# App store connect operation error the app references non-public selectors in payload after upgrading to Xcode 14.0 Flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter

Xcode version -> 14.0

**Error:**

The app references non-public selectors in Payload/Runner.app/Runner: fontWeight
relativeSize, spanArray, spanArray_Count, strikeThrough, underline

[image]

Comment: It looks like Xcode is complaining that you are using private APIs, most likely you are referring to private fields with KVC. Consider rewriting your code using public APIs.

Comment: I use Google Maps SDK and got this message as well. Somebody already filed a bug with Google. ( https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246667837 ) However, I just uploaded a new version to App Store and passed the review.

Comment: I have same issue. i find other people https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714736

Comment: This happens with Ionic apps as well currently (& Xcode 14.*)

Comment: To be clear, this is just a warning. Your build was still uploaded to App Store Connect  successfully, and Apple will still approve it (in my experience)

Answer (score 9):

I am also facing same issue but then i got one resolution please follow below steps :

1. Export .ipa file from latest Xcode
2. Install Transporter app on your mac
3. Login your App Store account in Transporter app
4. Add app using your .ipa file
5. click on deliver

Following this steps you can able to upload build successfully

Comment: Maulik's solution did not work for me.

Comment: Can I know what was issue in your side?

Comment: To clarify, the warning persists, but I am able to upload.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

- The same error occurs after the Xcode 14.0 update.
- Xcode 13.4.1 Download and Use Resolution

Answer (score 2):

For me it was I forgot to set `Build Configuration` to `Release` (earlier it was set to `Debug`). It was uploaded without any issues after I set it to `Release`

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to upload ipas to TestFlight via XCode 14.0.1 (build 14A400).
However, I was able to publish to TestFlight via Azure CLI with the same XCode and build versions. So, have no idea what might be the issue. I use Fastlane to upload the ipa.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same error in when upload build to TestFlight. Some frameworks are not updated for new IOS system because of that error is occurred like Lottie files are not supported. It has setImage: error. So update the all framework then try to achieve again.